# Syslog entries for local time update

Tags: embedded-linux, syslog, ntpd

There must be a syslog entry for ntpd daemon when it updates the local (client) time wrt server.

Grepping on my beagonebone syslog, I found this below entry for ntpd with respect to server:

```
proto: precision = 1.666 usec (-19)
```

Any lead for the log when ntpd updates the local time and how the log looks like?

Note: Not interested to query like `ntpq -p` or `ntpstat`.

Comment: I am able to see this line in syslog `ntpd[192]: time set +0.233850 s`

Answer (score 0):

Go to the download folder of your distribution builder (openembedded, buildroot, ...) and locate the source package for the ntp software. Have a look at the source. Only through inspecting the source you will know what a log entry actually means.